# I want to get the first 3 octets of my default gateway

Tags: powershell

```
$g = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_IP4RouteTable |
     where { $_.destination -eq '0.0.0.0' -and $_.mask -eq '0.0.0.0'} |
     Sort-Object metric1 |
     select nexthop, metric1, interfaceindex).nexthop
```

This command gives me the whole ip, like `192.168.1.1`.

I am interested in `192.168.1.`.

Comment: cannot use remove, because, some gateways can be like 10.10.x.y

Comment: `-replace '\d+$'`

Comment: `$addr.Split('.')[0..2] -join '.'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ip=(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_IP4RouteTable | where {'0.0.0.0' -in ( $_.destination, $_.mask)}).nexthop

# method 1
($ip -split "\.")[0..2] -join "."
```

Answer (score 4):

Some string manipulation would do it:

```
$g.Substring(0, $g.LastIndexOf("."))
```

Answer (score 0):

other solution

```
$template=@"
{SubIP*:0.0.0}.0
{SubIP*:255.253.255}.255
"@

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_IP4RouteTable | 
    where {'0.0.0.0' -in ( $_.destination, $_.mask)} | 
        %{ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template -InputObject $_.nexthop}
```